# Morning/Afternoon sun plants (vegetables)

Tags: vegetables, sunlight, shade

Is there a list one learning gardener can use to plan the position of plants depending on their preference of sunlight hours? I am interested in growing vegetables in a greenhouse.

I've read that some plants prefer morning sun, other prefer afternoon sun. Some plants grow in shade, others in full sun.

As I'm planning to grow dozens of different plants, I want to prepare the optimal environment for them.

(Additionally, if you happen to know and share where I can find each plant's best nutrient mix, preferred humidity, and light, I would be eternally grateful!)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This is quite broad - what sort of temperatures are you realistically going to be maintaining in the greenhouse? Heating them can be a lot more expensive and problematic than you might imagine. I would work backwards from there. The next step is to work out what you would like to grow (hint: what are you actually going to use, no point growing veg that you don't like or growing so many you can't use them all).

Comment: Hi George, I will grow them in an area with winter minimum of 0°C and summer maximum of 32°C. I am still calculating a lot of things in my plans but the end goal is to use solar panels and batteries to power the greenhouse. Do you think it would be very difficult to control the environment with electricity from solar (+batteries)?

Comment: How big is this greenhouse and what is it made from (glass/polycarb etc)?

Comment: I'm still planning it but my preliminary calculations suggest something in the area between 150-200 sq m with window height at around 2m and total height of around 3m.

Comment: I forgot to answer about greenhouse material, I'm not yet sold on any one. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

Your greenhouse should be oriented east west.  Your plant beds (and I recommend building your greenhouse over soil that you will simply add decomposed organic matter to as you build your beds and periodically cover the tops around the plants with decomposed organic mulch as well) should be north south (long axis).  Do not worry about morning sun or afternoon sun as all plants will get both, should get both.  Tall plants in the back so as not to shade smaller plants.  Most vegetable and flowering plants all need as much sun as possible so shade plants won't be an issue.[image: polytunnel over newly made beds]

South is to the left where the poly is lifted up daily for ventilation. Looking toward the west end of 'tunnel'.  Raised beds made from very non-fertile pumice soil with added bagged decomposed organic compost.

I've got pics of our new greenhouse with the same beds but they are not retrievable at the moment.  Made with dimensional lumber, same orientation.  Wall on south side should be made as low as possible and have the ability to open fully.  Best is the ability to have windows on the north side to get flow going.  Without opening these walls/windows the heat can quickly climb to past 100 degrees F.  It is a big big deal.  In addition, you need great fans to blow the air causing enough movement the leaves of your plants should move as well.  This is the best preventative for fungus problems which you WILL have.

The book you should get right away is by Shane Smith called 'Greenhouse Gardening'.  His information is easy to read, great pictures, graphs and very detailed information.  This book is one of my most used books in my library.

He will get into the different 'skins' of greenhouses and the pluses/minuses to determine the best for you.  Get the BEST you are able to afford!

Notice I never plant in rows.  Waste of space.  I also use pots and in the pots I only use potting soil from the store.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55203/discussion-between-georgi-pepelyankov-and-stormy).